# Instalar plugin de PHP para o editor Atom

Tags: php, atom

Já instalei vários *Plugins* do *Atom* para habilitar recursos para reconhecer sintaxe de *PHP* no meu projeto, mas não tive sucesso, qual é meu objetivo?
E quando eu digitar o código ele poder completar, veja o exemplo abaixo;

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h3>{{ $course->name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ $course->description }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

No exemplo, com o plugin instalado era para quando eu digitar **@forea**... e ele completar.

Eu só preciso saber qual o plugin certo para instalar no Editor Atom.

---

Com as sugestões que me passaram ele fica assim, mas não é do jeito que preciso;

Ao digitar o **@fore**.. não era para ele ter colocar o `<?php  ?>`

```
@<?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value): ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: utilizo bem pouco php, e utilizo o `language-php`, mas ele não consegue identificar as classe para dar sugestão no autocomplete, o resto não tenho o que reclamar

Comment: Se isso é o Blade templating engine de Laravel, que é o que me parece, há um plugin para isso no Atom que é o `language-blade` que funciona bem

Comment: Eu atualizei minha postagem, poderiam dá uma olhada por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Linter PHP seria uma boa solução, mas ele foi uma gambiarra temporária. Graças ao [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/), uma comunidade bem ativa e potente adotada pelo Facebook, agora o que era apenas um editor, acabouse transformando em uma verdadeira IDE.

Para fazer o seu Atom Editor se transformar em uma IDE oficial, é muito fácil. Vem comigo e siga os passos abaixo:

Instale o pacote [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui)
Instale o seu pacote de linguagem favorita. Neste caso, o PHP: [ide-php](https://github.com/atom/ide-php/)
Eu escrevi um artigo fazendo um review e um comentário mais bacana da ferramenta do Atom IDE. [Acesse este link para obter mais informações](http://binariux.com.br/seja-bem-vindo-ao-atom-ide/).

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que está a perguntar de um plugin para [Blade Templating Engine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade) em [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), existem vários no Atom.

Um que eu uso e funciona bem é o [laravel-blade](https://atom.io/packages/language-blade):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não só assinala a sintaxe com as cores corretas, assim como completa automaticamente as palavras chave:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu digitei nas configurações do Atom porém ele não encontrou o  laravel-blade, será que é para ficar tentando até encontrar?

Comment: @wladyband Chama-se "language-blade" . E lembre-se que apenas funciona num ficheiro blade, com extensão `.blade.php`